# JSlider with 2 data sources event handling

Tags: java, swing, events, jslider

I have a JSlider component on my frame which is being constantly updated by an external component (a media player which sets a new value from time to time).  I want the slider to handle the stateChanged event only when I manipulate the slider and not my external component.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You might use a `JProgressBar` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement my own [BoundedRangeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html), this way you can add additional flags that indicates whether it should accept updates or not

**UPDATE with EXAMPLE**

The basic idea would be to implement your own model, that way you can control when the value is actually changed

```
public class MyBoundedRangeModel extends DefaultBoundedRangeModel {

    private boolean updatesAllowed;

    public void setUpdatesAllowed(boolean updatesAllowed) {
        this.updatesAllowed = updatesAllowed;
    }

    public boolean isUpdatesAllowed() {
        return updatesAllowed;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMinimum(int n) {
        setUpdatesAllowed(true);
        super.setMinimum(n);
        setUpdatesAllowed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaximum(int n) {
        setUpdatesAllowed(true);
        super.setMaximum(n);
        setUpdatesAllowed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setExtent(int n) {
        setUpdatesAllowed(true);
        super.setExtent(n);
        setUpdatesAllowed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(int n) {
        super.setValue(n);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueIsAdjusting(boolean b) {
        setUpdatesAllowed(true);
        super.setValueIsAdjusting(b);
        setUpdatesAllowed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRangeProperties(int newValue, int newExtent, int newMin, int newMax, boolean adjusting) {        
        if (isUpdatesAllowed()) {
            super.setRangeProperties(newValue, newExtent, newMin, newMax, adjusting);
        }
    }

}
```

This would allow you to control the change of the "value" property.  The problem you have here is that ALL the set methods go through the `setRangeProperties` method, so you need to decide what should be allowed to effect it.  In my example, the only method that does not control it is the `setValue` method.

In your code you would need to call it something like...

```
MyBoundedRangeModel boundedRangeModel = new MyBoundedRangeModel();
slider.setModel(boundedRangeModel);

...

boundedRangeModel.setUpdatesAllowed(true);
slider.setValue(value);
boundedRangeModel.setUpdatesAllowed(false);
```

Your only other choice is to extend the `JSlider` itself and override the `setValue` method directly in a similar way

Comment: I need somehow to disable the "stateChanged" event when I update the slider from internal component. Is there some sort of handled method like in .NET?

Comment: Not in the `StateChanged` event